# Permission denied for ajax page in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, permission-denied

I am developing a site. I am getting content through ajax and showing it in a div.

The thing I don't understand is in IE I am getting error.

> Message: Permission denied in jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

The js file is in the same domain. It's not an Access-origin-policy problem.

And I have also searched in Google and found some answers like

- keeping meta tag as the first element in head
- content-type should be in small case

But none of these things work. What is this error exactly and how to debug it? The site works fine in Chrome and FireFox.

I am getting this error when I try to add a  tag to  in jquery.ajax() success like this.

```
$.each(response.scripts,function(k,v){
            var head = $('head');
            $("<script src='"+base_url+"js/"+v+".js'> </script>").appendTo(head);
          });
```

The problem doesn't occur when I hard code the  tag in the . But I want to add scripts through ajax. Is there a way to do it without problem in IE?

Comment: https may be problem too!

Comment: is there read permission for jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: Did you try this?: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908356/en-us

Comment: There is no frameset on the page and all the permissions are there for the js file. The site works without any problems in other browsers. This issue is also with only one page and nothing fancy with that page. Just some html